# Drupal 7 Add user delete tab in user profile

Tags: 7, users

I would like to show the user delete confirmation form as a tab in user profile, just near View and Modity. I am trying the following code in a custom module but it is not working, I'm not sure I am calling the right callback and arguments:

```
function custom_morebuttons_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/%user/cancel'] = array (
    'title' => 'Cancel profile',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('user_cancel_confirm_form', 1), 
    'access callback' => 'user_cancel_access', 
    'access arguments' => array(1), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) instead of [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) because you are adding a new menu item rather than altering an existing one.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/cancel'] = array(
    'title' => 'Cancel profile',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_cancel_confirm_form', 1),
    'access callback' => 'user_cancel_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 10,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'user'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Don't forget to return $items at the end of the function, since it is not passed by reference.

Though I'm not sure if the page callback and arguments are right, I didn't check that, I've just copied from your code.

Comment: I would add that the reason OP needs to use `hook_menu()` and not `hook_menu_alter()` is because they are not altering an existing entry, but adding a new menu entry; it just happens to be a subtab for an existing primary task.

Comment: This gives me this error: Notice: Undefined index: user_cancel_confirm_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (linea 763 di D:\Progetti\Sito\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\form.inc).
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'user_cancel_confirm_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (linea 798 di D:\Progetti\Sito\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\form.inc).

Comment: You need to also specify "file" and "file path" in the menu hook - see my EDIT.

Answer (score 6):

using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and a custom module

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['user/%user/canceltask'] = array(
    'title' => 'Cancel profile',
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_goto_user_cancel',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access arguments' => array('cancel_account'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
      'weight' => 10,
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule_goto_user_cancel($arguments=0) {
    drupal_goto('user/'.(int)$arguments->uid.'/cancel');
}
```

This solution offers the advantage of not needing to mess around with any forms at all. Its a simple redirect Button.

Comment: Not the most elegant of the solutions. But I like the simplicity :)

Comment: I dont think it's elegant to mess around in the system.  The other solution here might introduce problems with changing dependancies. starting with using $items['user/%user/cancel'] -> what will ensure this hook_menu is called after the other one? unsolved race condition I say..

Comment: In fact I used $items['user/%user/delete'] as $items['user/%user/cancel'] is already present in the user edit form.